# What is the difference between AppBar and Toolbar in MUI v5?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

What is the difference  between `AppBar` and `Toolbar` in MUI? I currently understand that the AppBar's flex direction is defaulted to 'column' while Toolbar's default flex direction is 'row.' Are there any other differences? Also why do all the examples for `AppBar` in MUI docs also  have a `Toolbar` nested inside? I currently use just the `Toolbar` and see no difference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `AppBar` purpose is just to be a container that allows you to set the position of it relative to the whole screen (i.e. sticky etc) and also to provide the background color which automatically changes if you are on dark or light mode.

The reason its separate is you might want to use `ToolBar` in contexts that aren't the primary navigation. E.g. a set of buttons above a table. When used inside the page contents like this, you don't want the block background color from the theme or position based on the whole screen since its inline.